# Mailchimp API and Repeatable Sections

Tags: mailchimp

Has anyone been able to successfully use the Mailchimp API to populate repeatable areas?

Have tried all sorts, but to no avail.

In the template, I have:

`div mc:repeatable`

div mc:edit="repeat_content"

This suggests that the array should be:

`$content['repeat_content'][] = "Content 1";`

$content['repeat_content'][] = "Content 2";

However, when calling campaignTemplateContent

It returns

array['repeat_content'] = Content1Content2

And nothing gets replaced in the Email that is sent.

When I remove the mc:repeatable div and just have mc:edit - the content is replaced fine.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

Each repeatable content section has its own unique mc:edit identifier...

If you use the templateInfo method and view the contents of the "sections" array, you will see each is appended with an index number (00, 01, etc...)

So in your example, the code would be something like:
$content['repeat_content00'] = "Content 1";
$content['repeat_content01'] = "Content 2";

etc...

Also important to note that through the API you cannot add repeatable sectinns - only populate the existing ones (you cant hide them either)....

The mc:edit fields govern the sections of a template..  When you create a campaign it copies the template into the campaign (visable with the camptaignTemplateContent method).

If you create a campaign on MailChimps site, repeat a section, and call the campaignTemplateCOntent method you will notice it does not include the repeated section/content...  The campaignTemplateContent is the raw copy of the template.

Now if you call the campaignContent method you will see the html (and/or text) content with repeated sections/modifications...

Think of it like this:
You have your templates.
When you create a campaign it copies the template into the campaign (campaignTemplateContent)

When you edit the campaign template in mailchimp's editor you can repeate sections.. The modified data is actually stored in the campaignTemplateContent section...

The MailChimp WYSIWYG editor (customized CKEditor) uses the mc:edit, mc:repeatable and mc:hidable tags to edit the campaignContent  (I am sure the editor also pulls from the campaignTemplateInfo).  But these tags mean nothing to the api.. The API just pulls the mc:edit fields to determine the custom content sections...

Ultimately, if you need an adaptable template for the API, you should create the content on the client side and then pass it to mailchimp.

---

Just an interesting observation I just found:  The MC editor pulls from the original template and stores the edited/ediable values in campaignTemplateContent...  (The rendered version is stored in campaignContent...)

The campaignTemplateContent is ordered by the order of the template mc:edit fields..

So when you modify a template the campaignTemplateContent fields will reorder based on the new template...

Also, after creating a campaign - if you edit the template and remove a section the section is still stored in the campaignTemplateContent...

Just interesting because somewhere in that mess is the logic for overcomming the ordering/sorting issue

Comment: Actually I was able to do iterations in template - see this discussion in api google group - http://groups.google.com/group/mailchimp-api-discuss/browse_thread/thread/4d4f4e22f3229dda. But still it is very unreliable because repeat sections don't maintain their names. I'm totally disappointed by the MC template API:(. Anyway thanks for your feedback, the bounty is yours:)

Comment: Did you actually get the repeatable sections working through the API, or are you editing the templates?   Igor's post provides some insight...   But did not clarify if it was the template or the campaign content...

Comment: Actually it was mine post in google group:). Yes in template I have repeatable section and when creating campaign content - I was able to repeat sections without using UI but only by providing carefully handcrafted hash with f*ked up key names.